# How to display array in Slack Webhook of Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have LogicApps. It receives property ListOfNames array in HTTP request.

I have difficulty to display correctly in Slack webhook. How to format body?

Current message displayed in Slack:
ListOfNames:
["Name1 \n","Name2\n","Name3\n"]

Target message in slack:
ListOfNames:
Name1
Name2
Name3

[image]

[image: I tried Split]

I tried Split:

Code: No errors, but don't array items listed correctly in message:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@split(string(triggerBody()?['ListOfTesNames']),'\\n') ",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "HTTP_Webhook": {
                "inputs": {
                    "subscribe": {
                        "body": {
                            "blocks": [
                                {
                                    "text": {
                                        "text": "*[dev] Testing:* \n ListOfTestNames @{outputs('Compose')}   ",
                                        "type": "mrkdwn"
                                    },
                                    "type": "section"
                                },
                                {
                                    "text": {
                                        "text": "Please check test results from database ",
                                        "type": "mrkdwn"
                                    },
                                    "type": "section"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "method": "POST",
                        "uri": "https://hooks.slack.com/services/1111111111111111111111"
                    },
                    "unsubscribe": {}
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "staticResult": {
                        "name": "HTTP_Webhook0",
                        "staticResultOptions": "Disabled"
                    }
                },
                "type": "HttpWebhook"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "staticResults": {
            "HTTP_Webhook0": {
                "outputs": {
                    "headers": {},
                    "statusCode": "OK"
                },
                "status": "Succeeded"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "POST",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "ListOfTestNames": {
                                "type": "array"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a compose connector before the webhook connector and use split functionality which gives the right format and then add the output of the `compose` connector to your `webhook` connector.

Here is a screenshot for your reference:

[image]

**Note:** Make sure you modify the expression in your split from `compose` connector as split(triggerBody()?['ListOfFiles'],'\n') to split(triggerBody()?['ListOfFiles'],'\n') because when we write the expression for this, it first takes '\n' as a string and then adds another ''.

Below is the split expression in compose connector:

```
split(triggerBody()?['ListOfFiles'],'

')
```

---

**Updated Answer**

As we are retrieving an array and passing it to the body of text it is adding the extra characters to it. We have created a new Logic App and added each item that we are retrieving to a variable and finally added that variable to the Webhook body.

Here is the screenshot of the logic app
[image]

Here is my code view

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "For_each_2": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Append_to_string_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "ListOfFilesFinal",
                                    "value": "@{items('For_each_2')},"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "foreach": "@split(item(),',')",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Foreach"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@triggerBody()?['ListOfFiles']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "HTTP_Webhook": {
                "inputs": {
                    "subscribe": {
                        "body": {
                            "blocks": [
                                {
                                    "text": {
                                        "text": "*[dev] Testing: * \n ListOfTestNames :  @{variables('ListOfFilesFinal')} ",
                                        "type": "mrkdwn"
                                    },
                                    "type": "section"
                                },
                                {
                                    "text": {
                                        "text": "Please check test results from database ",
                                        "type": "mrkdwn"
                                    },
                                    "type": "section"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "method": "POST",
                        "uri": "@listCallbackUrl()"
                    },
                    "unsubscribe": {}
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "staticResult": {
                        "name": "HTTP_Webhook0",
                        "staticResultOptions": "Disabled"
                    }
                },
                "type": "HttpWebhook"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "ListOfFilesFinal",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "staticResults": {
            "HTTP_Webhook0": {
                "outputs": {
                    "headers": {},
                    "statusCode": "OK"
                },
                "status": "Succeeded"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "POST",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "ListOfFiles": {
                                "type": "array"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: I tried split: InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose' inputs at line '1' and column '1535': 'The template language function 'split' expects its first parameter to be of type string. The provided value is of type 'Array'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#split for usage details.'.

Comment: try using split(string(triggerBody()?['ListOfFiles']),'\n') also can you please share what you are trying

Comment: Tried split(string(triggerBody()?['ListOfFiles']),'\n') but did not work. No error, but no change to message.

Comment: @Kenny_I would you mind adding code view of your logic app

Comment: @Kenny_I Change the marked term in this image https://i.imgur.com/9kVhsm1.png
to \n

Comment: If add "\n" to compose like split(string(triggerBody()?['ListOfTesNames']),'\n') . Then I get in code "inputs": "@split(string(triggerBody()?['ListOfTesNames']),'\\n') ",

Comment: Getting in slack: ["[\"Name 1","\",\"Name 2","\",\"Name 3","\",\"Name 4","\",\"Name 5","\",\"Name 6","\",\"Name 7","\"]"]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239351/discussion-between-swethakandikonda-mt-and-kenny-i).

Comment: Update answer did the trick I needed. New variable and For Each was really needed. Thank you very much!